# Convert Observable<Single<Object>> to Single<List<Object>>

Tags: java, rx-java2

Is there a possibility to convert `Observable<Single<Object>>` to `Single<List<Object>>`? I'd also like to know whether it's possible to make the observable to wait for all the underlying singles to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you could do it with something like this (untested):

```
myObservable
    .flatMap(x -> x)    // Flatten to Observable<Object>
    .toList()           // Collect in an Observable<List<Object>>
    .single();          // Convert to Single
```

Comment: I needed to use `flatMapSingle` instead but other than that everything is great! Thanks!